# Is possible to get the jquery object on which was called .children()? // I dont mean .parent()

Tags: jquery

I mean something like this:
`var children = $('#xy').children();`
and then 
`var xy = children.previous();` or something similar what returns #xy?
I dont mean .parent(). I mean $('ul') == all uls in document. .parent() returns olny one ul and i would like to have all the uls from first call of $('ul') if it is possible..
Thanks.

Comment: there is `.parent()` selector for getting immediate parent.

Comment: No I dont mean .parent(). I mean that object on which was called .children(). .parent() returns only the one ancestor of each children. I mean $('ul') == all uls in document. .parent() returns olny one ul and i would like to have all the uls from first call of $('ul') if it is possible..

Comment: Your question makes no sense the way it's written.  If you've attached `.children()` to `#xy`, then you already know these children came from `#xy`.

Comment: jQuery exposes the `.selector` property which may help, but it's deprecated

Comment: Look at the example what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/6db84mLf/2/ The first ul is not catched width .parent() . I only try to avoind traversing through the dom two times for two sets of elements, from which one is the children() of previous selector.

Comment: And it is very dynamic so I cant do it like `ul = $('ul'); ch = ul.children();` I have the children set at first and only in some case I need to get previous uls. May be it is the microoptimalization, but it is quite complicated script width draging and other functionality in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the parent, it's `.parent()`

https://jsfiddle.net/6db84mLf/

Update:

If applied to a set of many items `.parent()` will return a set of all the parents, which in absence of any manipulation in the meantime would be by definition the set on which you called `.children()`.

https://jsfiddle.net/6db84mLf/1/

Comment: No I dont mean .parent(). Lok at the previous comments what I mean.

Comment: No it isn't the same. Look at the update  https://jsfiddle.net/6db84mLf/2/ Thanks.

Comment: Are you wanting to retrieve the selector string which was used to select the original parents?